# How can I have getopt() support bundle of arguments and single character arguments

Tags: c++, getopt

I want to be able to support commands such as:

- `./myProgram -f required_arg1 -v required_arg2`

and

- `./myProgram -fv required_arg1 required_arg2`

Where `required_arg1` belongs to `-f` and `required_arg2` belongs to `-v` in both cases.

When the code below runs with the following command: `./myProgram -fv required_arg1 required_arg2`, `v` is instantly the argument to `-f`, but I want them to be independent of each other, but have their own `optargs`.

```
int opt;
int fflag = 0;
int iflag = 0;

while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "f:v:i:")) != -1) {        
    switch (opt) {
        case 'f':

            if (fflag) {
                cerr << argv[0] << ": cannot have more than one -f in same command.\n";
                return false;
            }
            else {
                fflag = 1;
            }
            
            if (fflag && iflag) {
                cerr << argv[0] << ": cannot have -i and -f in the same command.\n";
                return false;
            }
            
            cout << "arg for -f: " << optarg << "\n";
            break;
        case 'i':
            iflag = 1;

            if (fflag && iflag) {
                cerr << argv[0] << ": cannot have -i and -f in the same command.\n";
                return false;
            }

            cout << "arg for -i: " << optarg << "\n";
            break;
        case 'v':
            cout << "arg for -v: " << optarg << "\n";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is likely not possible, as getopt has a specific syntax it supports. But you shouldn't do this anyway, as it would confuse users who are used to the standard syntax.

Comment: Yeah I know I shouldn't be doing this, but some professors assign the wackiest homework assignments. I think I figured out a real "hacky" way by playing with the optind and argv.